# How can I define a new function in LaTeX (easy way to add \verb!word!)

Tags: verbatim

How can I define a new function in LaTeX? I want something like this:

```
%Current:
\verb!word!

I want something like this to do the same:
\vb_word
```

Or an easy way to add this function. I have more than 100 variables that I should add this function to it. It is hard to add two `!` for every word.

Comment: do you need verbatim? (there are no special characters in `word`?) `\vrb_word` would have no easily defined terminator, verbatim package makes it easy to define eg `|word|` with  just two `|`  but verbatim has lots of restrictions, why not `\texttt{word}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment. But your suggestions have `{}` or `||` in left and right sides. I'm searching a way to only paste a defined function in the beginning of my words.

Comment: but how do you define a word?  are greek letters in words, or accented letters, do words have a space to end the font change, or might it be a . or , or ... It is just massively more complicated and under specified what you want in that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Those are simple words. These isn't any space in middle, beginning or end of these words. These isn't any 'a' or 'or'. Just some words like 'X', 'x', 'format', 'file',

Comment: `simple words` doesn't discount Greek or Cyrillic or accented letters in an international forum but I posted something that works for ascii

Comment: What about `\vb{word}`?

Comment: If you are going to edit the document to add in `\vb_` in front of certain words, you can just as easily (with `sed` or `AWK` or `Perl` or ...) edit the document to add in just about *any* arbitrary string of text before and after any given word. With a proper editor like Emacs, you can do this interactively or non-interactively; I'm sure other decent editors can do so as well....

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do this but....

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\vb{\bgroup\ttfamily\xvb}
\def\xvb{\futurelet\tmp\xxvb}
\def\xxvb{%
\ifcat a\noexpand\tmp\tmp\expandafter\xxxvb
          \else\egroup\fi}
\def\xxxvb#1{\xvb}

\begin{document}


one \vb two  two \vb three, four (\vb five) six seven


\end{document}
```

[image]