# Define commands without the right bracket

Tags: macros

Is it possible to define a command without using the double left and right brackets? There are many occasions where I forgot to put the right bracket in a very long text and I spend enough time to find the missing bracket.  For example, I would like to define a command that replace the `\textbf{boldtext}` with a new command something like `\boldf/boldtext`, or `\boldf^boldtext` or `\boldf~boldtext` or `\boldf@boldtext`( or something similar. I dont care about `/`, `^` or `~` etc. These will play the role of  the left bracket) . Of course a space or a dot or a question mark etc. will play the role of the right bracket of the command.

Comment: Have a look at `xparse`. You can define commands with any delimiter you want. Just typeset the argument in `\bfseries`.

Comment: How should TeX know where the argument ends? You can use `\def` with basically any delimiter, but the right one is necessary

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a question asked yesterday, I gave an answer there (just change `\ttfamily` to `\bfseries`) but note the commentary on that question: you do not want to do this! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352811/how-can-i-define-a-new-function-in-latex-easy-way-to-add-verbword

Comment: This is more of an editor problem. Any well-bred editor, when you type an opening brace will automagically type the corresponding closing brace, and the cursor in-between.

Comment: What about `\textbf{All this text should be bold} and this text is normal`? How do you propose to cope with it?

Comment: @egreg I just want to have as little brackets as possible. The text is more error free. I am not talking about long paragraphs. I am talking only about an argument without any spaces inside. Maybe I will the xspace package...

Comment: @Christian Hupfer  Sure! I am asking if a space or . or ? etc.  (or all of them) could be used for the left delimiter...

Comment: @David Carlisle Excuse me I have not seen your answer, Thanks!

Comment: @kornaros: You can use `.` or `?` or a combination as well, but of course each macro name only once, i.e. you can't have both `\foo/foobar?` and `\foo/foobar.` for example

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer Mmm.. So, it  is not bossible to have different end  delimiters for the same command! Anyway... Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend this in general. There might be occasions where this needed, but not for pure lazyness ;-)

It is possible to define commands with 'arbitrary' delimiters with `\def`, for example.

```
\def\boldf/#1 {%
\textbf{#1}%
}
```

will use the `/` as left delimiter and (note the space between `#1` and `{`) a space character as right delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\def\boldf/#1 {%
\textbf{#1}%
}


\boldf/foo \boldf/foobar 


\end{document}
```

Comment: The code works nice! Just remember to place a space. So \boldf/haveagoodday! is different from \boldf/haveagoodday !

Comment: @kornaros: Yes, but you see, that there is not really a benefit each way. You need a right delimiter, call it `}` or `!` or whatever, it can be even another command, but it must be there.